# Add cron job via single command

Tags: cron, elementary-os

First of all, I'm using elementary OS (based on Ubuntu 12.04).

I have a cron job set up to run a script every day at 23:30:

```
30 23 * * * /path_to_script/
```

Is there a way to add it to cron via a single terminal command? All examples I've seen involve invoking cron first via `crontab -e` and then adding the job there.

I'd like a single command for doing this, something like:

```
cron add-job '30 23 * * * /path_to_script/'
```

Comment: @muru that accepted answer is a triple command on two lines (which admittedly could be made into a one-liner).

Comment: @Anthon yes, but OP seems capable of adapting it. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it with this:

```
{ crontab -l; echo "30 23 * * * /path_to/script/"; } | crontab -
```

Comment: Why disturb a `cat`? `{ crontab -l; echo "30 23 * * * /path_to/script/"; } | crontab -`

Comment: What is the difference between this command (or the one given by @muru) and: `(crontab -u userhere -l; echo "30 23 * * * /path_to/script/" ) | crontab -u userhere -` taken from http://askubuntu.com/questions/58575/add-lines-to-cron-from-script

Comment: @Gabriel The AU command explicitly specifies the user, otherwise there's no difference in effect.

Comment: You're right. Don't disturb the `cat`.